# Refactoring an OOP "decorator" to Free monad structure(s)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, free-monad

I have a bit of “legacy” Scala code (Java-like), which does a bit of data access. There’s a decorator which tracks usage of the DAO methods (collecting metrics), like this:

```
class TrackingDao(tracker: Tracker) extends Dao {
    def fetchById(id: UUID, source: String): Option[String] = {
        tracker.track("fetchById", source) {
            actualFetchLogic(...)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to model this as a Free monad. I've defined the following algebra for the DAO operations:

```
sealed trait DBOp[A]
case class FetchById(id: UUID) extends DBOp[Option[String]]
...
```

I see two options:

a) I can either make two interpreters that take `DBOp`, one performs the actual data access, the other does the tracking, and compose them together OR
b) I make Tracking an explicit algebra, and use a Coproduct to use them both in the same `for` composition OR
c) Something completely different!

The first option looks more like a "decorator" approach, which is tied to `DBOp`, the second is more generic solution, but would require calling the 'tracking' algebra explicitly.

In addition, notice the `source` parameter on the original `fetchById` call: it's only used for tracking. I much rather remove it from the API.

Here's the actual question: how do I model the tracking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not totally clear from your question, but if tracking is a sort of ambient effect that should "happen" when you perform db access and `source` is just an argument for tracking purposes, you may not have to mention it in your Free language at all. You can use the ADT you have now and interpret into `(Tracker, Source, OtherStuff) => IO[A]` for instance, so what you get back is a function that will produce a program to do DB access once you give it a `Tracker` and source and whatever else you need (DB connection for instance), and the tracking implementation is entirely private to the interpreter. This lets you write your database program without thinking about tracking at all.

If on the other hand you *do* need to talk about tracking in your business logic then we probably need more information about what it would mean to have multiple `Tracker`s and `source`s and how they're introduced and used. A coproduct or extended language or nested language might be necessary to deal with what you need to express.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I ended up doing something along the lines you suggested! Passing the 'source' ends up being a private concern of the interpreter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As in everything in our industry, the straight answer is "it depends" :). Since "tracking" is vague concept here (I don't know details of the domain), I would say that you have two possible scenarios (or at least I see two)

a) "tracking" is an element of your business vocabulary

If tracking is a separate concern that is part of the vocabulary that is used by your business, then I would go with a separate algebra representing that concern. Something similar to this would be "authentication & authorization"  - even though it is a "low-level" concern it  is still part of the business language ("As admin I want to...") I would go here with separate algebra

b) "tracking" is mechanism to some 'debugging',  'logging'

If tracking is not part of the language, but element of machinery that you keep for maintenance, then I would keep that in where it belongs  - the machinery. I would go with an interpreter that would side effect with 'tracking' (logging, debugging) those different calls.

In other words, if right now you don't have a single test that tests  "if I do this business thingy, then this should be tracked" then most definitely I would go with option b) here

Comment: I ended up accepting Rob's, but thank you for your answer :)